# Meaning of particle and word in provided sentence

Tags: particles

What is the meaning of this sentence 高橋ですが、今よろしいでしょうか, is が being used to indicate that the speaker has more to say. Also what is the meaning of でしょう in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The が here is kind of a softener/bridge/segue to the actual relevant clause which follows the first. Oftentimes this is conflated with が meaning 'but', however it is not always appropriate to translate it thus. You will see this use of が quite often in sentences such as すみませんが、トイレはありますか？ 'Excuse me, is there a restroom (here)?'. [This site](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-particle-ga.html) describes it as an 'introduction particle' and provides a few more examples.

でしょう expresses uncertainty in this case, as simply asking 今はよろしいですか might sound overly direct. Think of this as similar to when English speakers use 'Might now be a convenient time?' rather than 'Is now a convenient time?'. See the top [SE answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12977/whats-the-difference-between-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-at-the-end-of-a-question) for a bit more detail.

Comment: Just adding my two cents, でしょう makes the question _more indirect and therefore,  politer_.

Comment: why is desu after the name?

Comment: Can't desu just be ommited?

Comment: @user532874 If you're unaware, due to the lack of honorifics you can tell that Takahashi is the name of the individual who is inquiring about whether or not it might be an appropriate time. 'This is (Mr.) Takahashi, ... ' is what is being said. です should definitely not be omitted from this obviously polite/formal structure.